# Calculating the deviation from range of values?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

I'm trying to find if there is a function to do what I could do with several IF statements, just to make it more robust and standard I suppose (and more readable)

I have a spreadsheet with 4 columns of data

```
A    B    C    D
1200 1350 1700 []
100  120  50   []
```

A = Min, B = Max, C = Actual

I'd like to get the difference in column D. If C is less than A it should be A - C for example. If C is greater than B then it should be C - B. If C is between A and B, I want to display the deviation from the mid-point of A & B.

I could do this with some IF statements but I'm not sure if there is a better way to do this.

Edit: The IF statement method that I've done myself is as follows

```
=IF([@Actual] < [@[Min]],([@Actual]-[@[Min]]),(IF([@Actual] > [@[Max]],([@Actual]-[@[Max]]),([@Actual]-(([@[Min]]+[@[Max]])/2)))))
```

Which after an hour of playing around with seems to give me the results I want. But on a 400 Row, 48 page spreadsheet it's caused a fair amount of lag.

I guess the real question is, are there functions built in that could potentially yield the same results but with far less code/faster code?

Comment: You might be able to use divergence for this, but you'll have to study how it works for this situation.

Comment: @CharlieRB I've updated the question with some code that finally works. I was working on a formula and had to pop out for a bit.

Comment: Much better! Good job. I'll remove my comments to reduce clutter here. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You need two `if` and one `average` function, there is no built-in function for this calculation. If readability is really key for you then consider using some VBA and create a UDF.

Comment: This is really more of a comment than a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Consider:

```
=IF(C1<A1,A1-C1,IF(C1>B1,C1-B1,ABS(C1-(B1-A1)/2)))
```